# Extends the Request interface to add a fixed user property and extend any other class

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-passport

I'm doing a server-side application with [NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/) and TypeScript in combination with the implementation of [Passport JWT](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#implementing-passport-jwt).

**A little bit of context first:**

My JwtStrategy *(no issues here)*:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: 'hi',
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: IJwtClaims): Promise<UserEntity> {
    const { sub: id } = payload;

    // Find the user's database record by its "id" and return it.
    const user = await this.userService.findById(id);

    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return user;
  }
}
```

According to the documentation about the `validate()` method:

> Passport will build a user object based on the return value of our
> validate() method, and attach it as a property on the Request object.

Thanks to this behavior, I can access the `user` object in my handler like this:

```
@Get('hi')
  example(@Req() request: Request) {
    const userId = (request.user as UserEntity).id;
  }
```

Did you notice that I have used a Type Assertion (tells the compiler to consider the user object as UserEntity) ? Without it, I won't have auto-completion about my entity's properties.

As a quick solution, I have created a class that extends the `Request` interface and include my own property of type `UserEntity`.

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { UserEntity } from 'entities/user.entity';

export class WithUserEntityRequestDto extends Request {
  user: UserEntity;
}
```

Now, my handler will be:

```
@Get('hi')
  example(@Req() request: WithUserEntityRequestDto) {
    const userId = request.user.id; // Nicer
  }
```

**The real issue now:**

I have (and will have more) a handler that will receive a payload, let's call it for this example `PasswordResetRequestDto`.

```
export class PasswordResetRequestDto {
  currentPassword: string;
  newPassword: string;
}
```

The handler will be:

```
@Get('password-reset')
  resetPassword(@Body() request: PasswordResetRequestDto) {
  }
```

Now, I don't have access to the user's object. I would like to access it to know who is the user that is making this request.

**What I have tried:**

Use TypeScript Generics and add a new property to my previous `WithUserEntityRequestDto` class like this:

```
export class WithUserEntityRequestDto<T> extends Request {
  user: UserEntity;
  newProp: T;
}
```

And the handler will be:

```
@Get('password-reset')
  resetPassword(@Req() request: WithUserEntityRequestDto<PasswordResetRequestDto>) {
  }
```

But now the `PasswordResetRequestDto` will be under `newProp`, making it not a scalable solution. Any type that I pass as the generic will be under `newProp`. Also, I cannot extends `T` because a class cannot extends two classes. I don't see myself doing classes like this all the time.

**What I expect to accomplish:**

Pass a type to my `WithUserEntityRequestDto` class to include the passed type properties and also the user object by default. A way that I can do for example:

```
request: WithUserEntityRequestDto<AwesomeRequestDto>
request: WithUserEntityRequestDto<BankRequestDto>
```

And the value will be something like:

```
{
   user: UserEntity, // As default, always present
   // all the properties of the passed type (T),
   // all the properties of the Request interface
}
```

My goal is to find an easy and scalable way to extends the `Request` interface and include any type/class on it, while having the user object (`UserEntity`) always present.

Thanks for the time and any help/advice/approach will be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nestjs provides an elegant solution for your problem, which is [Custom decoration](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators)

*it's common practice to attach properties to the request object. Then you manually extract them in each route handler,*

What you have to do is create a user decorator:

**user.decorator.ts**

```js
    import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
    
    export const User = createParamDecorator(
      (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
        const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        return request.user;
      },
    );
```

then you can simply use it in your controller like this:

```js
      @Get('hi')
      example(@Req() request: Request,@User() user: UserEntity) {
        const userId = user.id; 
      }
```

Comment: Totally forgot about that possibility, thanks a lot, it's working nicely.